# i am installing magento2.3.3 in php8.0.7 but error showing in follwing

Tags: installation

Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2.3.3\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php on line 29

Answer (score 2):

Magento is not compatible with php8. Try the latest version M2.3.7 and M2.4.2 with  php7.4.

Magento 2.3.3 is compatible with php7.3

[Check system requirement from here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html)